# How to make TextInputEditText to be normal type after expand vertical?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, material-design

I had TextInputEditText inside TextInputLayout and set up android:inputType="textMultiLine". But when I entered and fill some texts into it, I cleared text with (.text = null) and delete text from button on keyboard. My TextInputEditText still keep expand vertical like this:

[image: this is image when I cleared text on it].

How can I make TextInputEditText become normal type before it expand with multiple line like this image [This is image when I don't entered or text into it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykIaP.png)

Here is the way I cleared text on edit text:

```
binding.chatEditText.text = null
```

and

```
binding.chatEditText.setText("")
```

Here is my code:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/chatTextField"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_margin="9dp"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@id/mircoBtn"
                android:elevation="15dp"
                app:boxBackgroundColor="?attr/boxBackgroundColor"
                app:boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd="25dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusBottomStart="25dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusTopEnd="25dp"
                app:boxCornerRadiusTopStart="25dp"
                app:boxStrokeWidth="0dp"
                app:boxStrokeWidthFocused="0dp"
                app:endIconMode="custom"
                app:expandedHintEnabled="false"
                app:hintEnabled="false"
                app:layout_anchorGravity="end|bottom">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/chatEditText"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Type Message"
                    android:singleLine="false"
                    android:maxLines="5"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                    android:textColor="?attr/colorControlNormal" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: .Thanks so much if someone can help me with this problem.

Comment: Can you show us how you style and set up your ```TextInputEditText```? And the code on how you clear the text?

Comment: Yes, I have updated my code as your request

Comment: My problem will happen when I set up edittext.clearFocus() or add icon to TextInputLayout with afterTextChanged. Just that :3